# Dynamic formula field with selected picklist

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, soql, apex

I am a newbie and I need little help, I have 2 picklists and based on the selection of the values of picklists I need to generate a dynamic calculated field on page. I know it is not possible using formula custom field, if it can be done using apex can anyone suggest me how with some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, if it can be done with a formula field, the best practise advise is to not use apex. In apex you'd cover this in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on how many combinations you have in your two picklsits. If they're up to 5 each (for instance) you could do this in a formula field quite easily with a nested IF or a CASE statement if you concatenate the values together. Something like this:

```
CASE( Contact_Type__c  &  LeadSource , 'CustomerCampaign', 'Customer originated from a campaign, 'SupplierCampaign', 'Supplier originated form a campaign',...,else_result)
```

If there are lots or combinations/permutations then a trigger might be a better solution.